# Ensuring one job per node for a specific rule

Tags: snakemake

Hello and thank you for reviewing this question!

I'm working on an SGE cluster with 16 available worker nodes. Each has 32 cores.

I have a rule which defines a process which must be run only one instance per worker node. This means I could in theory run 16 jobs at a time. It's fine if there are other things happening on each worker node - there just can't be two jobs from this specific rule running at the same time. Is there a way to ensure this?

I have tried setting memory resources. But setting for example

`resources:
    mem_mb=10000`

and running

`snakemake --resources mem_mb=10000`

will only allow one job to run at a time, not one job per cluster. Is there a way to set each individual cluster's memory limit? Or some other way to achieve one job per node for only a specific rule?

Thank you,

Eric

Comment: Could you clarify whether you're using drmaa or qsub? Also, is memory the limiting resource here? Scheduling based on available resources is what (ideally) the SGE cluster itself should do, I think.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this, bow. I am using qsub. It's a licensing issue that allows only one job to run per cluster node, so we run into errors if the scheduler puts two jobs on the same node.

Comment: Hmm..I'm not sure this can be solved by snakemake per-se, I'm afraid. You can, for example, make it so that your resource requirements results in one job per node. For example, if all your nodes have 16 cores, you can set all your jobs to require 9 slots. Of course this isn't really nice if most of your jobs use 1 core since you're essentially blocking other people out of the cluster. I would look into SGE complex_values: http://gridscheduler.sourceforge.net/htmlman/htmlman5/complex.html ~ maybe there is something there you can tweak (i.e. make the license a resource value).

Comment: Okay, thank you for your help! I'll keep trying things out and report back if I find an elegant solution.